# Для чего необходимо вызывать конструктор Parent`а?

Tags: java, наследование, конструктор

Для чего необходимо вызывать конструктор в `Parent` классе, из конструктора `Child` класса (или по крайней мере должен быть объявлен *default* конструктор в `Parent` классе)?

Ведь суперкласс может быть использован для хранения значений общих полей нескольких Сhild'ов, и иметь соответствующие `set()` и `get()` методы?

Comment: При создании экземпляра подкласса всегда первым вызывается конструктор его суперкласса. А потом уже дело доходит до конструктора подкласса. Это обязательное требование, независимое от обстоятельств. Именно поэтому вызов конструктора суперкласса будет всегда необходим

Answer (score 2):

Конструктор, например, позволяет инициализировать `final` члены класса, которые по завершении работы конструктора нельзя будет изменить ни `set()` методами, ни каким-либо другим образом.

Соответственно доступ к инициализации `final` членов `Parent`'a имеет лишь его собственный конструктор (даже конструкторы `Child`'ов имеют этот доступ лишь опосредованно, через синтаксис передачи аргументов тому же конструктору `Parent`'a).